# create syncml client and server

Tags: android, c, syncml

I want to implement the SyncML/OMA DS protocol for client and server for syncing data from device. I don't know how to implement SyncML for client and server for Android and low-end phones. I have searched online but there's only PDFs of SyncML and some site say to download there software for SyncML server.

I want to make SyncML server and also client side without any software. Is any API for SyncML available & where can I get it?

Comment: Funambol has an open source client. There's no "OMA DS/SyncML" API available on Android in the SDK - some phones come with OMA DS clients. Unless you know what you are doing (sounds like you don't) you're probably not going to write a client that will be able to interoperate with many existing servers - so make a Funambol adaption would be my recommendation. If you are dead set on "rolling your own", KXML can parse the SyncML WBXML format at least.

Comment: thanks but if we use funambol then we have to use it's api for client side . can any better way to sync device data other then sync-ml. Actually we provide UI and use sync-ml for sync.so if we use funambol then we have to use it's UI .i have to make my apps.

Comment: Funambol has a client (& server) SDK if I remember correctly, hosted [here on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/funambol/). The license is Affero GPL, but I guess you could pay for a non-GPL license if you intend to make a closed source adaptation.

Comment: what if we don't want use funambol or other software , is there any API for sync-ml is available so that it can be implemented in client side and server side ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but there is a library available that should do what you want if you are able to make it work on android.
https://gitorious.org/libsynthesis